# How to run two versions of QGIS simultaneously on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I really enjoy seeing the new features and icons of QGIS 1.9 nightly versions.
It's looking fantastic, and some features are already very useful for my work.

However, it is inherently less stable than QGIS 1.8 as it's a development version.

To deal with this, I generally keep QGIS 1.9 installed and updated on my system, and use it until something I need does not work (this happens every fortnight or so - most commonly with plugins such as ftools and [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46645/openlayers-plugin-and-qgis-1-9-error-after-install)). At this point, I uninstall v1.9, remove the ubuntugis repository, and proceed to install v1.8.

This solution works fine, but I was just wondering if there's a better way? How would I go about running 2 versions of QGIS simultaneously (with updates), one for stability, the other for features, fun and bug-checking? And is it worth doing?

One solution I tried a while back was to clone the [github version](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS) into a new folder on my machine and run that binary when I wanted the latest version...

Comment: I have Windows 7 x64 and have installed the weekly build (#28) via the pre-compiled installer only to find that I can no longer launch QGIS 1.8. QGIS 1.8 now crashes during loading. Is there a simple way to recover from this situation and get back to using 1.8. Ideally, I would like to have version 1.8 and a weekly build available on the same system.

Comment: The Question is about QGIS 1.9 and your "answer" is about QGIS 1.8.  To me it looks like you should pose a new question (unless it has already been answered elsewhere).

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to GIS Stack Exchange :) Although related to the original post, you would like both stable and dev versions installed and usable simultaneously, this isn't an answer and should be a new question along the lines of "how to troubleshoot QGIS crashing on startup? (after multiple installs)". [@PolyGeo: he listed 1.8 as broken, but it was installing 1.9 that did the breaking]

Comment: Andrew, after you recover your broken environment, [Curlew's answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/63401/108) will get you what you want. Osgeo4w qgis-dev is updated nightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which system are you using? On Windows you could just use the [OSGEO4W installer](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download):

- Select advanced Install
- And download and install `qgis` as well as `qgis-dev` from the list

to have both version running on your pc.

On Linux have a look at this post of mine [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52409/how-to-setup-qgis-master-and-stable-in-parallel-on-one-linux-system).

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 - should have mentioned it. Many thanks for the link.

Comment: FYI I followed the advice of Gary Sherman and installed QGIS in a separate directory. You need to build qgis from source to do this I think: from here http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#71-Source-Code (I used current 1.8 branch). In there you'll find some instructions to build with cmake. It installed in a new directory. Then set the path variable: "PATH=\$PATH:~/qgis/bin" >> ~/.bashrc and changed the name of the binary to "qgis1.8".
One remaining issue: this version does not enable new packages.

Answer (score 0):

I am running a Windows 7 system, with QGIS 1.8 standalone and OSGeo4W with QGIS Master.

Apart from that, I have installed Oracle Virtual box, once with ubuntu 12.04 and QGIS stable, and a second one with ubuntu 12.10 and QGIS master (to test both of them).

Windows and both virtual boxes run completely indepently from each other (even simultaneously), but can access the same data sources in shared folders.

And, yes, it is definitely worth doing so.