# How to install two versions of QGIS on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I would like to run multiple versions of QGIS on Ubuntu 12.04. Can I do that, and how if so?

Comment: have you considered using a VM?

Comment: That is an awesome suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that, but it is more than likely going to require you building your own version in conjunction with you installing one from the package repository.

This post on here has some of that information in the comments of the highest answer.

[How to run two versions of QGIS simultaneously](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63398/how-to-run-two-versions-of-qgis-simultaneously)

I also googled around and found this:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail//qgis-user/2012-November/020026.html

which also is along the same line.  Basically it is not going to be easy if you are not really familiar with building from source and managing installation of custom software under linux.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. In fact, I'm just seeking for guidance. I know that someone as already put this question but the building from the source is not so easy. Considering a virtual machine is not a solution for me as I have a old machine with only 2GB of RAM.

Comment: I agree building from source it not easy, but that is pretty much the surest way you are going to be able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

One can install NextGIS QGIS (2.18.21) using this PPA (https://launchpad.net/~nextgis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nextgis/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ngqgis
```

But be careful with python-ngqgis package as it overwrite python-qgis to work qgis plugins (make sense only for two QGIS 2.x, for QGIS 3.x and NextGIS QGIS will be fine).