# Downgrading QGIS on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis-3, installation, ubuntu

I updated to QGIS 3.4 on Ubuntu, but there are some functions that are not working so I want to downgrade. Therefore, I have several questions:

1. How to downgrade or reinstall to some older version easily?
2. A safe, standard and easy way to install multiple QGIS versions on Ubuntu?

**Please Note:** I have investigated a few similar questions but they are old and related to QGIS 2, nevertheless, QGIS 3 has significant changes.

Comment: It depends on which QGIS and Ubuntu version you want to run. QGIS 2.18 is still available as LTR, but QGIS 3.0 and 3.2 might need self-compiling once the packages have been updated. You can only have multiple QGIS versions on Ubuntu using virtual boxes or dockers.

Comment: `apt-cache policy qgis` shows you what you can get from packages.

Comment: You can install QGIS 2.18.25 from NextGIS PPA (https://launchpad.net/~nextgis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages). See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287941/9904. This version works with QGIS 3 on same PC.